# Passing down props through multiple components nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm new to `Next.js` and have problems sharing data between components. I have three components:

```
//index.js
function App() {
   const options = []
    for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        options.push({
            label: i,
            value: i
        })
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Form options={options}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

```
function Form({options}) {
    return(
        <form>
            <Select options={options}/>
        </form>
    )
}
```

```
function Select({options}) {
    options = options?.map(option => {
        return <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
    })
    return (
        <select>
            {...options}
        <select/>
    )
}
```

This is a simplified version of the code.

When I run this code I get this `Error`:

`x Spread children are not supported in React.`

This is because the options variable is not updated with the `map` function, when I run this code inside the select element of the `Select` component:

```
{console.log(options)}
```

I get an array of objects with objects that looks like this:

```
{
    $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
    key: "1",
    //etc....
}
```

When I run this `console.log()` inside the `Form` component I get the array that I created inside the `index.js` file.

I feel like this has something to do with the `Server-Side-Rendering` in `NextJS`.

Comment: you don't have to do this {...options} , you can directly use <select>{options}</select>. It will work.

Comment: You are right! But the reason I get this error is that options is not an array of component or elements, because the map function hasn't done it's job due to the SSR.

Comment: No .. its not because of map function or SSR, map function returns an array , so `options` is basically an array , so for destructuring contents of array you will have to spread like this `{[...options]}`.

Comment: trying this I get TypeError: undefined is not iterable, because options is undefined

Comment: Where are you doing this between <select> tags only? If yes, then you should not get error .

Comment: Yes, but I think the problem isn't about destructuring the array, because this --> {options} would work too, if the 'options' was defined.

Comment: So did you remove `options = options?.map(option => {
        return <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
    })` this?

Comment: @SonamGupta I had multiple forms in my index.js that used this 'Select' component, and on the one that was visible on my screen I had forgotten to pass the options as a prop. So you are right the problem wasn't the SSR nor the map function. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Try, This because you are trying to do a map options data and put that into the select tag that is why select doesn't recognize your spread options data and you just need map that options data inside the select tag

```js
function Select({options}) {
    return (
     <select>
       {options?.map((option) => {
           return <option value={option.value}> {option.label}</option>;
       })}
    </select>
  );
```